# Neural Network input layer with many zeros

Tags: neural-network, lstm

I want to design a neural network, an **LSTM** actually, which can analyze the function call log of an application. My goal is to get my system able to understand if any given functions call sequence is malicious or not. The sequence should also include the arguments for each function call.

My design involves an input layer where neurons groups concern a single call function with its arguments.

This design also implies that if I ever get this network trained, my input will always be a sequence of zeros, a few numbers different from zero, and other zeros.

Can this neural network design ever work? 
Is there any best practice I'm not aware of that states I should avoid a design like that?

**Updates**

My intention is to define the input as a sequence of numbers.

Function arguments which are not numbers, such strings, are converted into numbers by some heuristics.

Assume the following as a possible input of the NN:

`{[0,0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0,0],[1.2, 3.45, 5.33, 9.10],[0,0,0,0,0]}`

*Brackets are there just for convenience because I plan to make my input as a sequence of numbers without any structure.*

The following is the representation of this scenario:

you have a space of 5 functions with the following signatures:
(for convenience I made all arguments float)

```
f1(float a,b,c,d)
f2(float a,b)
f3(float a,b,c,d)
f4(float a,b,c,d)
f5(float a,b,c,d,e)
```

and the input I included above is the case where system is evaluating a the safety of a call

```
f4(1.2, 3.45, 5.33, 9.10)
```

Comment: Also: What is the dimensions of your input data? How is the data represented (i.e. how is the function call log "converted into numbers")?

Comment: It's near impossible based on your information to decide whether it would work. It would depend on how well the information is presented in the data, and how the LSTM handles it. If the sparsity is sufficiently high along the time-axis, most time series method is going to fail, especially the data driven ones as e.g. LSTM.

Comment: To test the performance, you could make toy data that is somewhat similar to your dataset and see if it performs well on that. If that fails, I'd try to find other, perhaps more statistically motivated, methods that are designed to deal with sparse data.  Alternatively, representing the data differently could make it less sparse.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Still in the design phase, not sure of anything. 
I'm not asking the assurance it would work, but because I'm not an expert, I'm asking if there's anything well known (not by me obviously) why this design couldn't work.
I updated my original question to give you more details on what I'm asking.